# Best Practices for updating permission sets in managed package to reduce and expand permissions?

Tags: apex, managed-package, permission-sets, isv

Per this article, we cannot update permission sets in managed packages:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_perm_sets_profile_setttings.htm

When updating permission sets in managed packages, what are the best practices? I am currently looking at permission set groups and then having individual permission sets underneath the group. I see how this could work well for expanding access to objects, but when it comes to reducing/deleting the permission sets in the group, I believe we will see issues.

Overall, I am looking for the best practices for permission sets in managed packages so that I can easily update each permission set behind the scenes without my subscribers having to reinstall the package.

Comment: The doc you linked to says permission sets can be upgraded in managed packages. Likewise, you can see it's upgradeable [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm)